# Finding pow(a^b)modN for a range of a's

Tags: c, algorithm, math, modulo

For a given `b` and `N` and a range of `a` say `(0...n)`,

I need to find `ans(0...n-1)`
where,

`ans[i]` = no of `a's` for which `pow(a, b)modN == i`

What I am searching here is a possible repetition in `pow(a,b)modN` for a range of `a`, to reduce computation time.

Example:-

if `b = 2` `N = 3` and `n = 5`

```
for a in (0...4):
    A[pow(a,b)modN]++;
```

so that would be

```
pow(0,2)mod3 = 0
pow(1,2)mod3 = 1
pow(2,2)mod3 = 1
pow(3,2)mod3 = 0
pow(4,2)mod3 = 1
```

so the final results would be:

`ans[0] = 2 // no of times we have found 0 as answer .`

`ans[1] = 3`

`...`

Comment: Which coding contest this problem is from?

Comment: Please give an example so that we understand the problem.

Comment: Not sure to understand your exemple. You wrote pow(3,2)mod3 = 2. But pow(3,2) = 9. And 9mod3 = 0.

Comment: @GerardWalace oops .. updated.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't `ans[0]` be `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm have a complexity of O(n).
Meaning it take a lot of time when n gets bigger.

You could have the same result with an algorithm O(N).
As N << n it will reduce your computation time.

Firts, two math facts :

```
pow(a,b) modulo N == pow (a modulo N,b) modulo N
```

and

```
if (i < n modulo N)
   ans[i] = (n div N) + 1
else if (i < N)
   ans[i] = (n div N)
else
   ans[i] = 0
```

So a solution to your problem is to fill your result array with the following loop :

```
int nModN = n % N;
int nDivN = n / N;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (i < nModN)
        ans[pow(i,b) % N] += nDivN + 1;
    else
        ans[pow(i,b) % N] += nDivN;
}
```

Comment: `"Your algorithm has a complexity of O(n)"` - I'm not sure I'd consider `a^b` to be an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: You're right. But it depends on your processor architecture. On x86, it's supposed to be a time constant operation for exemple. Nevermind, I must admit I may have over simplified my compexity calculation by not taking this into account as it affects both of the algorithms the same way. Thanks for the remarks.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate `pow` for primes only, and use `pow(a*b,n) == pow(a,n)*pow(b,n)`.

So if `pow(2,2) mod 3 == 1` and `pow(3,2) mod 3 == 2`, then `pow(6,2) mod 3 == 2`.